# Get the four newest date in an Array and ath them to new Array

Tags: c#, arrays, umbraco, ienumerable

I was wondering who to add the four latest NewsEntries to an array

```
IEnumerable<PageNewsEntry> allNews = node.Children<PageNewsEntry>();
IEnumerable<PageNewsEntry> latestNews = new List<PageNewsEntry>();
```

First array, has all the news on it. Second array needs to get "foreached" in order to render the html.

A `PageNewsEntry` has the property Date on it which is da Date. I was wondering how to add the four latest news to the `latestNews` - Array

I get the date from a news like this: `allnews.foreach(var news in allNews){news.Date}`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to add the four latest NewsEntries to an array

You can use `OrderByDescending` and `Take`

```
var top4LatestNews = allNews.OrderByDescending(n => n.Date).Take(4).ToList();
```

If you really need an array(in your code you use a list), use `ToArray`.